# Equivalent definitions of strongly convex functions

Tags: convex-optimization

i am looking for a short proof for a theorem of a book:

[image]

$f\in S^2_\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)$ means that f is strongly convex with parameter $\mu$ i.e

[image]

2.1.17 you can find in
[image]

theorem 2.1.11 says i just have to apply 2.1.17 but i don't know how to do it

thanks for your help

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: The definition 2.1.2 describes $S^1$, but the upper text discusses $S^2$, so maybe you haven't looked in the correct place for the right definition.

Comment: introductory lectures on convex optimization: a basic course by Yurii Nesterov

Comment: $S^2$ means that the function ist two times differentiable

Comment: The reason this proof is abbreviated like this is because it's almost a duplicate of a previous proof in the book, with the small change from convex to strongly convex. I'm a little bit mystified why you asked the question, unless you skipped over most of the book and just landed at this proof. Surely it would be a good idea to read the entire chapter otherwise of course you will be mystified when you just jump onto a particular theorem on a particular page.